# Why doesn't my Jinja2 template work?

Tags: python, jinja2

My Jinja2 template is supposed to automate the HTML structure from my index page. Nothing shows up on the browser when I run and browse the program. It DID work when I used one variable, but something goes wrong when I nest several. Here is the code:

```
class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        stage = [name, lessons]
        name = 'Stage 1'
        lessons = [
                    ['Lesson 1 Important Concepts',[
                        ['HTML', 'HTML is the ...'],
                        ['Tags and Elements', 'This is an e...'],
                        ['Why Computers Are Stupid', 'Computers ne...'],
                        ['Inline and Block Elements', 'Block elem...']
                    ]
                ]
                    ['Lesson 2: Creating a Structured Document with HTML',[
                        ['Developer Tools','Everything design...'],
                        ['HTML is Structured Like a Family Tree','HTML..'],
                        ['Text Editors','HTML is writt....'],
                    ]
                ]
                    ['Lesson 3: Adding Style to HTML Using CSS',[
                        ['Avoiding Repetition','If programm...'],
                        ['CSS','CSS, or cascading style sh....'],
                    ]
                ]   
                    ]   
        self.render("index.html", name=name, lessons=lessons)
```

Here is the template:

```
<h1> {{name}} Important Concepts</h1>
{% for lessons in stage %}
<div class=“lesson”>
    <h2>{{ lessons[0] }}</h2>
    <div class="concept”>
        <div class="concept-title">
            {{ lessons[0][0] }}
        </div>
        <div class="concept-description">
            {{ lessons[0][1] }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

My GitHub project is here: https://github.com/graceehayden/Stage4Udacity-Session-2

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gracehayden/Desktop/Udacity/Stage4Project/main.py", line 22, in get
    stage = [name, lessons]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Dont you get any syntax error? And, I do not see any stage1 variable you are passing to jinja.

Comment: I do get an error, but I don't understand it. The stage 1 thing though - that's a good point!  You'd think it would be obvious, but I'm such a slow learner that I guess I get overwhelmed and can't see those details!  Hence, my appeal.

Comment: also, instead of using list of lists, you should consider using a dictionary or few of the to spare those funny indexing `[i]` and `[i][j]`. It will make your code more readable.

Comment: OK, I added the error. I'm not well-versed in using dictionaries, but I'll do some research. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: The problem is the line `stage = [name, lessons]`. It should be the last line in that method, after `name` and `lessons` are declared.

Answer (score 0):

Values can only be used **after** they've been defined. Thus, instead of:

```
stage = [name, lessons] # this fails because "name" and "lessons" aren't yet set
name = 'Stage 1'
lessons = [] # big value here
```

Reorder these lines to put the definitions of `name` and `lessons` (defining their values) *before* the place where those values are used to define `stage`:

```
name = 'Stage 1'
lessons = [] # big value here
stage = [name, lessons]
```